# how to load large json data [2gb] into php?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

JSON file name:  *testjsonfile.json*

Size of the "testjsonfile.json" is 2GB.

How to load json file?
Code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents(testjsonfile.json'), TRUE); 
print_r($data);
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1310720) (tried to allocate
>   1719707520 bytes) in test.php

Note: 
Increased memory limit

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '4000M');
```

Comment: you may look into stream reading the json. Search on google, you may find the solution

Answer (score 2):

Use something similar to
https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

This streams the data in so will use less total memory rather than having everything in memory

Answer (score 0):

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '20000M');
```

To the top of your script. Change the 20000M accordingly.